# Long frames in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js

Not sure how to interpret these long frames in Chrome Dev Tool (performance tab). This is a profile of an animation in React. I am using d3-timer to run the animations which is using requestAnimationFrame. There's is noticeable jank in the animation from these sporadic long frames (between ~50 and ~70ms). But I don't see any red like you normally see when you're dropping frames.  Here's a screenshot...

[image: performance profile]

**Question:** What can cause random long frames like this?  In this example it looks like the RAF is running multiple times during that one frame and it doesn't show any other activity causing the frame to be delayed. So how would you diagnose the problem?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'd be glad more screenshots or information if it would be helpful.

**Note:**  I am not posting code because it's not really about the code.  I am asking how ANY code could end up profiled like this.  Where the frame rate drops and multiple RAF frames end up inside a single "frame" in Chrome Developer Tools.  Wondering if anyone has seen this before and might be able to shed some light?

Comment: Not related to your question: why are you using `d3.timer()`? Why not using `transition()`?

Comment: Right.  Can't directly manipulate the DOM in this project.  Animating component props and state.

Comment: This question is a perfect example of why you are required to provide "*the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**" (quoted from the CV reasons). How should anyone be able to help you with the information you provided? Ths is just poking around in the dark. Please set up a [mcve] and I am sure there will be many folks willing to assist.

Comment: I think his question is perfectly valid, he is asking how to interpret what the dev tools are telling him, not how to fix his exact code

Answer (score 0):

As near as I can tell, this is a bug in Chrome's performance tools.

I had the same issue as you, but much more obviously not a problem with my app: [image: Screenshot of Dev Tools]

In my case this is a WebGL2 page with a simple shader and basically nothing happening aside from calling `requestAnimationFrame`. As you can see, there is virtually no load, but there are still the puzzling notches where frames appear to be dropped.

I say "appear to be" because you can see that the GPU and compositor are still active, as if they're rendering a frame at the normal time - there's just no marker in the dev tools saying that a frame happened.

So I downloaded the profile, which is just a JSON file, and dug into it further. The lines in the profile that signal the beginning of the frame are these:

```
{"args":{"frameSeqId":94370284,"layerTreeId":1},"cat":"disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline.frame","name":"BeginFrame","ph":"I","pid":5640,"s":"t","tid":6908,"ts":1839098089419},
```

The key part is the `"name":"BeginFrame"`. I'm not sure what the timestamp (`ts`) values are based against, but they're in microseconds, and when the logs are properly aligned these are definitely the events for the start-of-frame lines. And they exist for the supposedly "dropped" frames in my trace! Whatever is causing the profiler to not show them, it's due to some other data.

I will try reporting this as a bug, and see where it goes. Edit: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1339567